# Push_back a variable to vector

Tags: c++, vector, push-back

Just started learning STL and here is the first problem:

```
  vector<int> vec1;

for(int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
{
    vec1.push_back(i);
    cout << vec1[i] << endl;
}
```

As you may see i want to push back variable **i** to vector **vec1** but output is:

```
5832900
-319008141
0
```

etc...

```
Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.210 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Thanks for anything.

Comment: Arrays start from 0, not 1. Anyway, `std::iota` is a good candidate here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pushing on the back, but printing out item[i], which is one past the end (i starts at one in your loop).

```
vector<int> vec1;

for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    vec1.push_back(i+1);
    cout << vec1[i] << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are printing one beyond the end of the vector each time. This would be a correct version of your code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    vec1.push_back(i+1);
    cout << vec1[i] << endl;
}
```