# using a single variable the data in the vectors should be added

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, vector

I am using Visual C++ for my program.

I want to create a program by which externally a stream of data can be fetched to the system and with a precise sampling rate the data is saved into the vector automatically.

The first part is almost done but the data that i need to save in vector is to be done by automatically updation as the value is fetched. For eg.

```
myVector.push_back(fetched_value)
```

Can i use vectors like this? Since the `fetched_value` variable will have new value each time when the loop is run.

Comment: sorry to bother you guys!!!
i got my ans in the below link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13129292/push-back-a-variable-to-vector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: Yes, you can.

Long answer: 
`push_back()` will create a copy of the value in this case.
Just take care that the copy will make sense in this case.

e.g. If you read your values into a char buffer and will use `std::vector<char*>` you will only store the address to your buffer and not the data.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back